# Правильно задать параметры для строки запроса ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть вот такой "велосипед":

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}/{token}")]
public IActionResult AccountActivation(int id, int token)
{
    User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Перейдите по ссылке отправленной на вашу почту для активации аккаунта";
        return View();
    }
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.Status == token.ToString())
        {
            user.Status = "active";
            db.Update(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "Аккаунт активирован";
            return View();
        }
        else if (user.Status == "active")
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Аккаунт уже был активирован";
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Токен не соответствует";
            return View();
        }
    }
    ViewBag.Message = "Перейдите по ссылке отправленной на вашу почту для активации аккаунта";
    return View();
}
```

Вопрос в том что когда к примеру перехожу по ссылке:
https://localhost:44305/accont/accountactivation/4/514298604
то надпись об ошибке: "Не найдена страница для адреса...".
Думаю что ошибка в том что неправильно задал параметры запроса потому что раньше более одного не использовал и могу сейчас тупить.
Вот фрагмент из Startup:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{token?}"
    );
});
```

Самое главное что все работает и даже этот метод, но если делать запрос к этому же методу с параметрами то выдает ошибку.

Comment: `/accont/` - в ссылке опечатка наверное.

Comment: @aepot к сожалению нет потому что без параметров id и token все работает. Вот это корректно:[HttpGet("{id?}/{token?}")]     ?

Comment: [Вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

ссылка с параметрами выглядит вот так
https://localhost:44305/accont/accountactivation?id=4&token=514298604

Попробуйте вот так

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AccountActivation()
    {
        int id;
        int token;
        String sid =  Request.QueryString["id"];
        if (sid != null && sid.Length > 0)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(sid, out id))
            {
                //we have id
            }
            else
            {
                //can't parse id 
            }
        }
        String stoken = Request.QueryString["token"];
        if (stoken != null && stoken.Length > 0)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(stoken, out token))
            {
                //we have token
            }
            else
            {
                //can't parse token
            }
        }
        

        User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Перейдите по ссылке отправленной на вашу почту для активации аккаунта";
            return View();
        }
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.Status == token.ToString())
            {
                user.Status = "active";
                db.Update(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Аккаунт активирован";
                return View();
            }
            else if (user.Status == "active")
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Аккаунт уже был активирован";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Токен не соответствует";
                return View();
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Перейдите по ссылке отправленной на вашу почту для активации аккаунта";
        return View();
    }
```